# DateTime.ParseExact: "String not recognised as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I'm trying to send a JSON request from a javascript application, and create this object (HourRegistration) in my SQL DB, but for some reason, I can't parse the date from json, to a valid DateTime.

**JSON date from JS**

```
hourRegistration.Date = "12/08/2015";
```

So `dd/MM/yyyy`

I'm trying to parse like so:

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(hourRegistration.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

**Entire method**

```
public void CreateHours(HourRegistrationDTO hourRegistration)
    {
        DAO.Instance.HourRegistration.Add(new HourRegistration()
        {
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(hourRegistration.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Cust_ID = hourRegistration.Cust_id,
            Login_ID = hourRegistration.Login_id,
            Hours = hourRegistration.Hours,
            Comment = hourRegistration.Comment
        });
        DAO.Instance.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**ToCharArray()**

[image]

I don't really know why this doesn't work. As far as I recall, this should work?

Comment: Just tested your code. All okay. Maybe because you use `hourRegistration.Date`. instead of `hourRegistration.date`?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov Typo. It's `hourRegistration.Date` (edited main question)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I get the error that's in the title of the question

Comment: Can you please debug your code and see what `hourRegistration.Date` is exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül it is exactly `"12/08/2015"`

Comment: @Detilium if you try parse this date as string - all okay?

Comment: what's the value if you hourRegistration.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov It is already a string. In my Javascript I convert this Date to a string, so it's just returning pure string

Comment: @KarmaEDV The same as the string `"12/08/2015"`

Comment: We need more work from you on making a *minimal* example. If you explicitly set `hourRegistration.Date = "12/08/2015";` just before the `DAO.Instance.HourRegistration.Add` line, what happens? If you examine the *character values* of the string value of `hourRegistration.Date`, is there any Unicode weirdness? etc

Comment: @AakashM If I set `hourRegistration.Date = "12/08/2015"` everything works fine.

Comment: Great, now we know that `ParseExact` isn't broken! Change your `var tmp` to `var tmp = hourRegistration.Date.ToCharArray();`, then inspect `tmp` in the Locals window. Are there exactly 10 elements? Are they 49, 51, 47, 48, 56, 47, 50, 48, 49, 53 ?

Comment: @AakashM More like 49, 51, 47 and so on. What the solution to that?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your Locals window?

Comment: @AakashM As I've never worked with "Locals" window before, I need you to help me on this one?

Comment: @Detilium Create string variable like `strDate = "12/08/2015;"` and compare it to your datetime `bool IsEqual = strDate == hourRegistration.Date;`  Debug it and tell us if this is true or false. If it is false you can compare them char by char and find what is different

Comment: or just a screenshot showing the debug expanded view of the `tmp` character array

Comment: Your string isn't what you think it is. Post a screenshot showing the character array values.

Comment: @AakashM See main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string value in `hourRegistration.Date` is not what you think it is.

With strings in .NET, there are many Unicode characters which either do not appear at all in the debug representation, or are not in fact the characters they appear to be. In your case, as shown by the `ToCharArray` debug expansion, your string actually contains a number of [`U+200E` Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (U+200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) characters.

These are invisible in the debug representation, but ARE relevant when trying to parse the date. I don't know how they got there or why they are there - that's something you'd need to research further.

To solve your immediate issue, before parsing your date, remove all non-ASCII characters from your string, along the lines of:

```
var actualDateString = new String(hourRegistration.Date
                          .ToCharArray()
                          .Where(c => c <= 255)
                          .ToArray()
                       );
```

(I've just banged this out so it's not very pretty)

Then you should be able to parse `actualDateString` as required.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Appreciate the time you've used solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This gives no error:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/08/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

, so the problem has to be somewhere else.

I have to assume that your `hourRegistration.Date` variable is empty string. In that case you get the exception `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`
Debug the value before parsing.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment it shoud be no problem to give us a screen capture like this:

[image]

Just to make sure and clarify the problem scope...
Thanks!

**EDIT 2**

This could sound weird:

Try renaming your `string` property and see if it's fixing the issue.
See the following behavior on a `string` object called `Date`

[image]

Can someone tell me why is handled as `DateTime` object in debugger? it's clearly a `string` variable.

*Update*: This issue has been detailed here: [String variable name Date acts weird in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005674/string-variable-name-date-acts-weird-in-debugger/)

Comment: You are assuming it is empty string but OP says it is `12/08/2015`. I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: If you've read the comments, you would know that my string isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious for the moment that your string has some other characters. You can try to remove this characters using simple custom method like this:

```
    static string Validate(string dirty)
    {
        string validChars = @"0123456789/-\."; string newStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dirty.Length; i++)
            if (validChars.IndexOf(dirty[i]) > -1) newStr += dirty[i];
        return newStr;
    }
```

And use it like :

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Validate(hourRegistration.Date), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try that:

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(hourRegistration.Date, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-Ru"));
```

Comment: But, why? Why OP need `ru-Ru` culture instead of `InvariantCulture`? That doesn't make sense for this case.

Comment: Because "dd/MM/yyyy" is date in ru-Ru culture format, but as for me both versions work well, and return the same result

Comment: OP _already_ provide an exact format of it's string with valid culture setting. He doesn't need to use other culture.

Comment: Delimiter is no matter

Comment: He is trying to parse something with a specific format (dmy plus invariant culture delimiter). To use another specific culture just because it happens it matches that format is simply **wrong**. Moreover it also accepts (your code) other unrelated formats.