# String variable name Date acts weird in debugger

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, visual-studio-2015

Can someone tell me why is the debugger handles my `string` variable named `Date` as a `DateTime` object?

Code:

```
public class HourRegistration
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

See screen capture:

[image]

Using .NET framework 4.5, VS-2015

Thanks!

**Update:**

By reducing the code to smallest possible, I found to obvious problem.

Minimally reduced code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }

        public static void DoSomething()
        {

            DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact("asdasd", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public class HourRegistration
        {
            public string Date { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

It was a different variable in another context named exactly the same as the string, and the debugger showed the details of the other object (based on context)

Comment: What have you set that to? Do you have any custom visualizers installed? What sort of app is this? (If you can reproduce this in a console app, it would be particularly interesting.)

Comment: I can't currently reproduce this - it's not even clear what the context is, to be honest - is execution currently stopped in the `Date` getter? Somewhere else? (I'm wondering which instance it's looking at...)

Comment: I am reducing the unnecessary code. Debugging someone's code. Trying to make a small console app to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I hope I didn't take too much of your time.

Comment: While I agree that the Visual Studio could do better here, this is nothing new. The same would happen if you just type "Date" in the watch window. Current context is important.

Comment: Interesting - I can now repro...

Answer (score 0):

```
//There in your above question you are creating a new object with datatype as datetime and variable as Date but this Date is not the one you described in your model.For that you have to do something like below:


HourRegistration model = new HourRegistration ();
     model.Date = DateTime.ParseExact("asdasd", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();

//But this code gives an error since you cannot pass a string value to date.It makes no sense.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking for variable values in debugging mode, it matches by name, not by memory address.

I agree to others, it could be done better, moreover I've seen this *issue* in previous versions (at least vs 2013).