# converting an existing date to another date c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Wanted to pass a string value of **8/26/2015 8:00:00 PM** for conversion to 
**2015-08-26 20:00:00.000** in SQL.

But before I could do that,

> string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

```
DateTime clock = Clockval.StartTime.Value.Add(Clock.StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay);
theStartTimeConvert = DateTime.ParseExact(clock.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", null).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Did I pass in the wrong codes? And is there other alternatives to convert to **2015-08-26 20:00:00.000** from DateTime?

Comment: What that for: `DateTime.ParseExact(....)` in your code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov changing **8/26/2015 8:00:00 PM** to string, then to the format of date

Comment: So you have `DateTime` value, you convert it to string, than parse - how/why you expect this will impact the value?

Comment: Just insert `clock` into database, It will automatically formated according to SQL server culture settings as `2015-08-26 20:00:00.000`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov To change to the date format

Comment: @X-TECH oh! But I am receiving **string was not recognized as a valid datetime.** when submitting the datetime. I'm not sure if it is because of the **PM**, that's why I decided to change the date format..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the `M` custom format specifier represents the month as a number from 1 through 12. You use it to parse number 23.
Second, since your months and hours can have a single digit you should use `M` and `H` instead of `MM` and `HH`:

```
var str = "8/26/2015 8:00:00 PM";
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formattedDate = parsedDate.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

If format works fine with my `str`, but doesn't work with your `Clock.StartTime.Value.ToString();` - I guess you can have issue, that was desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003910/datetime-parseexact-string-not-recognised-as-a-valid-datetime/32004334#32004334). To cut the long story, sometimes strings isn't what you think is it. There a lot of Unicode characters which don't appear in the debug representation. Try to work with this string for parsing:

```
var str = Clock.StartTime.Value.ToString();
var correctDateStr= new String(str 
                               .ToCharArray()
                               .Where(c => c <= 255)
                               .ToArray());
```

Comment: thanks but I am already using it and it gave me **string was not recognized as a valid datetime.** error @Artem Kulikov

Comment: Are you sure you used exactly this "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" format? As I tested on your date and all looked ok. Can you provide date with error?

Comment: The value displayed **8/26/2015 8:00:00 PM**. I came up with the format after looking at the tables and it shows **string was not recognized as a valid datetime** @Artem Kulikov

Comment: Well, let's try to find out the problem. Can you help me with this? First of all - run please my code as it is (copy all three lines and execute). Will it provide an error?

Comment: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.** error is displayed.

Comment: I modified the codes abit `var str = Clock.StartTime.Value.ToString();
                            var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            var formattedDate = parsedDate.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: it works with your str. So it means the format is the issue

Comment: I have an idea. Updated my answer, check it please.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I found the answer it is M/ **d** /yyyy h:mm:ss tt! And I have tried your code. But it does not read var correctDateStr= new String(str.ToCharArray() **.Where(c => c <= 255)** .ToArray()); cause it cannot read **c** and **.Where()** method

Comment: Glad that you have found out the solution. About `where` - you should add namespace `System.Linq` to use it.

Comment: The linq works!!! But it didn't convert the date and it's okay! Cause thanks to you I got a working date haha :D